# How to use IF statement using multiple conditions, AND and OR

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-columns

Please see attached image

[image: Screenshot of Excel Document]

I have listed all the possible combinations for either a Yes or No in Checklist field.

1. English speaking always has to be Yes, to return Yes in checklist
2. Months has to be 6 months or more, to return Yes in checklist
3. PPS has to be 50 or less, to return Yes in checklist
4. Decision making and if not,Family fields are interchangeable, either can be Yes, to return Yes in checklist
5. If the family field shows no or left blank and the decision making field is Yes, return Yes in checklist.

Hope this makes sense. I have tried the below but it just doesn't fully work, I am confused by so many different fields.

```
=IF(OR(AND(M21=2,F21<51,G21>5,K21=2), AND(M21=2,F21<51,G21>5.9,I21=2), “Yes”, “No”)
```

```
=IF(OR(M22=2,F22<51,G22>5,I22=2,OR(M22=2,F22<51,G22>5,K22=2)), "Yes", "No")
```

**I just tried this formula, It won't work can someone help**

```
=IF(OR(AND(T21>=50,U21>5,H21=“Yes”,J21=“Yes”), AND(T21>=50,U21>5,H21=“Yes”,L21=“Yes”), “Yes”, “No”))
```

Comment: Create a helper column for each of your 5 rules - and then it is pretty easy to build the final result

Answer (score 0):

Rule 5 seems obsolete to me.... isn't that covered in Rule 4? At any rate, here's how I did it, using Minimally reproducible data:

```
=IF(AND(B2<51,C2>5,D2="Yes",OR(E2="Yes",F2="Yes")),"Yes","No")
```

So it's just an AND formula wrapped with an IF formula.

The AND conditions include:

```
Logical 1: B < 51
Logical 2: C > 5
Logical 3: D = Yes
Logical 4: Either E or F = Yes
```

If for some reason you believe Rule 5 is not covered in Rule 4, then simply add another Logical Condition to the AND part of this formula.

[image]